# how can i make a binary matrix from a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that looks like this:

```
> df.head()

    Name     Application
   manager1     word
   manager2     mail
   manager2     internet
   manager1     excel
   manager3     word
```

I try to make a binary matrix from this, but can't find the solution.

```
Name      excel   internet  mail  word
manager1    1         0       0     1
manager2    0         1       1     0 
manager3    0         0       0     1
```

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df.Name, df.Application)`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) with `max`:

```
df1 = pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('Name')['Application']).max(level=0).reset_index()
print (df1)
       Name  excel  internet  mail  word
0  manager1      1         0     0     1
1  manager2      0         1     1     0
2  manager3      0         0     0     1
```

Or with aggregation `max`:

```
df1 = (pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Application'], prefix='', prefix_sep='')
         .groupby('Name', as_index=False)
         .max())
print (df1)
       Name  excel  internet  mail  word
0  manager1      1         0     0     1
1  manager2      0         1     1     0
2  manager3      0         0     0     1
```